# How rename "cancel" button in ImagePicker(IOS)

Tags: react-native, expo

I use ImagePicker from Expo. Cancel button in the image library recording in English. But my devices have Russian language. How to rename this button in Russian?

[image: ios screenshot]

`````
import {ImagePicker} from "expo";

   let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
          quality: 1
    });
    ````
`````

Comment: Did you see the official documentation of imagepicker?

Comment: yes, https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/  this companent don thave language options